# What is name for imagine line in graph?

Tags: functions, terminology

[image: Image of graph that have dotted line]

I have solid line which connects point of real data which is collected from experiment, and dotted line which connects point with imagine data (average between two values) to continue graph in places where we didn't collected data.

Is there any specific scientific name of this dotted line?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Maybe search for _interpolation_...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes, that's looks like what I'm looking for! Thank You!